# Control-R stopped working, I have to press Control-Shift-R instead

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, 18.10

Before, I could hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in GNOME Terminal to enter Bash's `(reverse-i-search)` mode.

However, this stopped working, the cursor just flashes without doing anything. This also affects remote and container shells (where it was working before).

Although I've noticed, it works when I'm pressing: <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

I'm using GNU bash v4.4.19 on GNOME Terminal v3.30.1. I'm not sure if this is some new feature of Ubuntu Cosmic, or something else.

It seems, this also affects web-browsers, where I've to press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the page, and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't take any effect (Chrome and Opera).

My keyboard works fine, I don't have *Caps Lock* enabled, and I'm not using any custom programs to modify the default shortcuts and I've never changed any. The issue is reproducible all the time, I've tried this already over hundred of times, the same effect.

**How do I change the shortcut back to previous default combination (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>)?**

---

What I've tried:

- *Reset All* Keyboard Shortcuts to default in Ubuntu *Settings*.

---

Here are few details:

```
$ bind -p | grep 'search-history'
"\C-s": forward-search-history
# non-incremental-forward-search-history (not bound)
# non-incremental-forward-search-history-again (not bound)
# non-incremental-reverse-search-history (not bound)
# non-incremental-reverse-search-history-again (not bound)
"\C-r": reverse-search-history
```

I've checked, and I don't override the above bindings in my *dotfiles*:

```
$ grep -r reverse-search-history ~/.bash*
(nothing)
```

Comment: The output of `bind -p | grep 'search-history'` might be helpful

Comment: @steeldriver I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had this problem and realised I had SimpleScreenRecorder running which was capturing the CTRL+R hotkey.  Hope this helps any googlers!

Comment: Holy sXXt man, so it's not just *my* fail ;)

Comment: lmao thank you very much. I felt like a moron googling "control r search stopped working"

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and recently installed TinyTake. As a web dev, I've been having an awful time trying to understand why my refresh shortcut didn't work anymore. Not even PowerShell's reverse-i-search, everything needed to be ctrl+shift+r.  It didn't even occur to me that having TinyTake running in the background would DO this to my basic keyboard shortcuts.  But sure enough, exiting the app, restored my regular keyboard shortcuts.   CRAZY.   Thanks for the answer!

Comment: omfg you are a hero :)

Comment: Thanks so much! In my case it was app 'TinyTake by MangoApps' running in the background. Im on Win10.

Comment: I uninstall it. But the shortcut remains not working. How can I restore it?

Comment: damn, same here! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is experiencing the same problem, check if you have [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) installed. It binds the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to use the fuzzy finder.

First, make sure it's in your `$PATH` by running `fzf` from a terminal. If it's not in the path, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will silently fail.

If it's there, make sure to [upgrade](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#upgrading-fzf) it to the latest version.

> `CTRL-R` - Paste the selected command from history onto the command-line
>
> - If you want to see the commands in chronological order, press `CTRL-R`
>   again which toggles sorting by relevance.

I was using `fzf` version `0.18.0` with Ubuntu 18.04.4 and the reverse search was broken. Upgrading `fzf` to the latest version available (`0.21.1`) and executing the install script again solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it would always happen when a Cisco WebEx reminder on the side of my screen was showing.  It wasn't the active screen but sure enough when I close the reminder Cntl-R and other keys begin working again.  Took me a bit to connect the two problems together.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue from time to time when using `zsh` with oh-my-zsh package and `tmux`.

Current workaround for me is to apply:
`bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward` in given pane.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the **AOC I-Menu** blocking it. Have to close the program and reopen it every time when I want to adjust my screen brightness...